# Isolating thread-unsafe initialization functions

Tags: c, multithreading, libcurl

Suppose that I have a C library that requires initialization and cleanup functions that aren’t thread-safe.  Specifically, these functions may invoke other thread-unsafe functions in other libraries.  I don’t know (in a default build) which libraries these will be.

Now consider the case of writing Java bindings to this library.  Java spawns multiple threads before running any Java code.  Worse, in the case of (say) an Eclipse plugin, there could be multiple threads running Java code by the time my code receives control.  Some of the other threads could be using the aforementioned unsafe functions.

My current plan is to statically link the C library (in my case, libcurl) and *all transitive dependencies* – in my case, a TLS library (probably mbedTLS) and (on Windows platforms) the CRT.  Fortunately, libcurl cleans up everything it has allocated, so problems related to allocating from one heap and freeing it on another should not arise.  Because everything is statically linked, and won’t try to load any other shared libraries, I can then initialize libcurl from a static initializer.

Will this even work?  Is there a better way?

Edit: The reason that serializing library calls won’t work, and that I believe that my solution might work, is that the global state is stored not only in libcurl itself, but also in libraries libcurl depends on.  Some of these libraries (ex.  OpenSSL) might be in use by other code when my code is loaded.  So I would need to lock against the entire process.

The reason I believe that isolating the global state *would* work is that libcurl (and every library it depends on) is thread safe after initialization.  I need to make sure that the *initialization​* of libcurl doesn’t create race conditions.  Afterwards I am fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated and revised]

Your concern seems to be that you will have both direct and indirect bindings to some native library -- say mbedTLS --, that that native library requires one-time initialization that is not thread-safe, and that, beyond your ability to detect or control, different threads of the process may concurrently attempt to initialize that library, or perhaps may (unsafely) attempt to initialize it more than once.  That certainly seems to be a worst-case scenario.

On the other hand, you postulate that you can successfully build a monolithic, dynamically-loadable library containing the native library you want along with the transitive closure of all its dependencies (outside the kernel), so as to ensure that this library does not share state with any other library loaded by the process.  You assert that after a non-thread-safe initialization, the combined stack will be thread safe, at least as you intend to use it.  You want to know about how to initialize the library.

***Java promises that each class will be initialized by exactly one thread, and that afterward its initialized state will be visible to all threads.***  Although that does not explicitly address the question, it certainly implies that if the initialization of your native libraries is performed entirely as part of the initialization of a class -- *e.g.* via a static initializer, as you propose -- then the correct initialized state will be visible to all Java threads.  That adequately addresses the problem as I understand it.

I remain dubious that building the monolithic library is *necessary*, but if you truly have to deal with the worst-case scenario you seem to anticipate then perhaps it is.  Inasmuch as you cannot isolate the library from conflicting demands on the kernel, however, it is conceivable that the strategy will not be *sufficient*.  That would be one of the few conceivable good reasons for a library to rely on the kind of shared state you postulate, and your strategy would thwart that particular purpose.  I cannot judge how probable such an eventuality might be, but I doubt it's very likely.

Comment: My problem is that the C library *does* use global state, and some of its dependencies may *already be in use*. I don’t control any of the code except for the binding code.  So I need to ensure that libcurl’s initialization doesn’t clash with other libraries’ initialization.  Hence the need for multiple copies.

Comment: I am not willing to serialize all the JNI calls, nor do I believe that would solve the problem.

Comment: @Demi, if you want a more confident or more specific answer, then you'll need to be more specific in the question about exactly what kind of problem you are concerned about.  What is the imagined nature and scope of concurrent use of the same libraries?  What is the nature and scope of the shared global data?  And regardless of your willingness to synchronize accesses, I'm curious about why you think that would not solve the problem.

Comment: See edit — in short, some of the global state could already be in use by other threads.  So I need to make sure libcurl uses its own copy.

Comment: I have updated and revised my answer, but at its core it remains the same: the strategy you propose should work to avoid an initialization race.